# Straightforward memory management in gSOAP clients and servers (especially servers)

Tags: memory-management, server, client, gsoap

I'll admit that I sometimes skim through previous questions and think I'm encountering a lot of off-context fluff, so I'll try to make this concise.

If a server uses soap_new_T(soap) to allocate (including soap_new_ptrTo_T(soap) instead of soap_malloc whenever possible), it seems not only superfluous but counterproductive to use soap_end anywhere outside of soapC.cpp or soapcpp2.cpp.

On the other hand, which I have yet to attempt, is it sensible to use soap_new(soap) for any allocation preceding a SOAP request and use soap_end() or some other function/method upon return when calling from a C(++) client? Or even new()/delete() or (m/c)alloc()/free(), for that matter?

What purpose, other than the premature dumping of XML, is served by soap_end???

What I'm trying to accomplish is to place dynamic memory under the scope of gSOAP, so that it is automatically released once its utility completes. Experiments suggest that the proper use of soap_end occurs when needed, without my intervention. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not soapcpp2—stdsoap2!

Comment: Admittedly, soap_end() may have a useful debugging purpose in grabbing the XML before it has any chance of reaching the client and dumping it to stdout or stderr. Why would I want to make this a routine part of any functional code to be released???!!! (And even then, it's only machine-readable XML! And this is coming from someone who coverts hex to ASCII in his head!)